# SharePoint Designer - edit content type column (e.g. rename)

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

This should be possible. But it isn't. Rename is greyed out.

Here is what I did.

- I added columns.
- I added a content type and added the columns to the content type.
- Next I assigned the content type to a list.

If I go to Content Types -> my content type -> edit columns -> I can see all my columns but I cannot change them to required/optional or even change their display name.
If I click on "Administration Web Page" I'm being redirected to the ManageContentType.aspx page where I can indeed change a field from optional to required (for example). I cannot rename the display name though... but there's simply no such option in the web interface. But I'm pretty sure I have done that multiple times with declaratively deployed content types :)

Any ideas? SP Designer 2013 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell about SPD, but in webeditor (sp2013) you can go to ribbon->list->list settings and there rename any column.
Edit: ok, i've found how to do it in SPD: go to your list, on ribbon click Edit columns; then right click on any column and select Rename

Comment: This seems more suited to a comment, maybe give some more detail and expand your explanation a bit.